# SQL fetch all in a self-join construction

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My current database looks like

```
CREATE TABLE sites(
siteId INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT,
siteType VARCHAR(255),
siteName VARCHAR(255),
siteDomain VARCHAR(255),
PRIMARY KEY(siteId)
);
CREATE TABLE siteSites(
parentId INT(11),
childId INT(11)
)
```

I'm trying to join all the tables and fetch all data.
like:

```
<?php
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sites s1, siteSites, sites s2 WHERE s1.siteId=parentId AND s2.siteId=childId");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($q);
?>
```

and than i want to get both the info from 's1' and 's2' out of the $row variable.
is this possible and if it is than how do i do it?

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT s1.siteId as ParentSiteId, s1.siteType as ParentType, s1.siteName as ParentName, s1.siteDomain as ParentDomain,
       s2.siteId as ChildSiteId,  s2.siteType as ChildType,  s2.siteName as ChildName,  s2.siteDomain as ChildDomain
    FROM sites s1
        INNER JOIN siteSites ss
            ON s1.siteId = ss.parentId
        INNER JOIN sites s2
            ON ss.childId = s2.siteId
```

Comment: but how would i retrieve the values from $row since the column names are the same in 's1' and 's2'?

Comment: thanks, this was pretty much what i wanted to avoid, any chance it's possible without having to create aliases for each column? so just with selecting *?

Comment: @user746379: No. As you pointed out yourself, the column names would be the same for `s1` and `s2` if you don't alias them individually.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear...

If I'm making any sense of it, you'd like to pull the entire graph in a single query. If so, no, this is not possible in MySQL. Doing so would require a [recursive with statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-with.html).

If not and your current query is correct, you need to alias the column names rather than `select *`, i.e. something like:

```
select s1.siteid as parent_id,
       s1.sitename as parent_name,
       ...,
       s2.siteid as child_id,
       s2.sitename as child_name,
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question.
Try this:

```
SELECT s1.*, s2.*
FROM sites s1 JOIN siteSites ss
ON s1.siteId = ss.parentId
JOIN sites s2
ON ss.childId = s2.siteId
```

Answer (score 0):

You only missing the while loop:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
echo $row['siteName'];
echo $row['siteDomain'];
echo $row['parentId'];
// etc ..., access to values by field name
}
```

Comment: @user746379: That is correct but if you only need 1 row, you can add `LIMIT 1` at the end of your query, so only one row is transfered.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you need theme all.